# Infinite Scroll NGX error en el orden del array

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo un scroll infinito con posts, pero tengo el siguiente problema os pongo un ejemplo...

```
Post1
Post2
Post3
```

Hago Scroll para ver los siguientes post... y pasa lo siguiente

```
Post1
Post4
Post5
Post3
Post6
```

Me aparece el array desordenado osea no se guarda el orden, que puede estar sucediendo? cada vez que hago scroll crea un array.

```
  onScroll() {
    if (!this.finished && this.page !== null) {
      this.anunciosSearch.getAnunciosSearch(this.page, this.termino)
        .then((data: any) => {
          this.anunciosList = this.anunciosList.concat(data.results);
          console.log(this.anunciosList);
          if (data.next === null) {
            this.finished = true;
          } else {
            this.page = data.next;
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: EN la consola te salen ordenados o no?

Comment: Me salen desornados en la consola, haciendo un console.log al array me los muestra desordenados

Comment: En ese caso tendrás que ordenar el array tras la concatenación, no?

Comment: Exactamente, eso es lo que no se como hacer :/

Comment: Mira el método [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: Gracias voy a verlo

Comment: Nada... no lo consigo this.anunciosList.sort()

Comment: necesitas pasar la función que compara elementos a ese método